# Find Sub range of values in defined ranges

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have 3 ranges of data values in series:

min_range:

```
27    893.151613
26    882.384516
20    817.781935
dtype: float64
```

max_range:

```
28    903.918710
27    893.151613
21    828.549032
dtype: float64
```

I have created a list of ranges:

```
range = zip(min_range, max_range)
```

output:

```
[(893.1516129032259, 903.91870967741943), (882.38451612903225, 893.1516129032259), (817.78193548387094, 828.54903225806447)]
```

I have got a sub range:

sub-range1: 824
sub-range2: 825

I want to find the region in which the sub range lies.

```
for p,q in zip(min_range, max_range):
    if (sub-range1 > p) & (sub-range2 < q):
        print p,q
```

output:
    817.781935484 828.549032258

I want to find the respective position from that defined "range".

Expected Output:

```
817.781935484 828.549032258
range = 2 (Position in the range list)
```

How can i achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use enumerate to get the index i.e

```
for i,(p,q) in enumerate(zip(min_range, max_range)):
    if (sub_range1 > p) & (sub_range2 < q):
        print(i)
```

Output : 2

Comment: I am assuming `p` and `q` are floats. In this case, do _not_ use bitwise operators.

Comment: instead of & to use `and` ?

Comment: If they aren't series/dataframes, then `&` is a bitwise AND, not a logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach using counter.

```
cnt = 0
for p,q in zip(min_range, max_range):
    if (sub-range1 > p) & (sub-range2 < q):
        print p,q
        print cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1
```